# Need to print a statements based on an IF and ELSE constriction

Tags: sql, database, oracle, if-statement, plsql

1. If the SUM of the order is >100 and < 200 I need to reduce the price by 10%
2. If the SUM of the order is >200 I need to reduce the price by 20%

   ```
   BEGIN
   FOR item IN(SELECT ORDER_LINE.O_ID,SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE) AS SUM,
   SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE) -SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE)*.10 AS TEN,
   SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE) -SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE)*.20 AS TWENTY
   FROM INVENTORY
   INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE
   ON INVENTORY.INV_ID = ORDER_LINE.INV_ID
   INNER JOIN ITEM
   ON ITEM.ITEM_ID = INVENTORY.ITEM_ID
   GROUP BY ORDER_LINE.O_ID
   ORDER BY ORDER_LINE.O_ID)
   IF item.SUM > 100 AND item.SUM < 200 THEN
   LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
   item.O_ID||' '||item.TEN);
   END LOOP;
   ELSE IF item.SUM > 200 THEN
   LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
   item.O_ID||' '||item.TWENTY);
   END LOOP;
   END IF;
   END;
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in your sql:

```
SELECT 
  ORDER_LINE.O_ID,
  CASE WHEN 
    SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE) > 100 AND SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE) < 200 
  THEN
    SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE)*0.9
  WHEN SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE) > 200 THEN
    SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE)*0.8
  ELSE
    SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE)
  END SUM
FROM INVENTORY
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE
ON INVENTORY.INV_ID = ORDER_LINE.INV_ID
INNER JOIN ITEM
ON ITEM.ITEM_ID = INVENTORY.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY ORDER_LINE.O_ID
ORDER BY ORDER_LINE.O_ID
```

Pay attention that in your sample when sum=200 there are no discounts.
I'd suggest that you need to check sum >= 200 instead.

Comment: How can I get the second CASE WHEN to run?

Comment: Make SUM(INVENTORY.INV_PRICE) more then 200?

Comment: It worked! But I had to remove the second CASE word from the code! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: @JuanCarlosHernandez yep, sorry, was too lazy to check sql >.<